# Ideal way to perform lookup on a stream of Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have the following use-case:
There is a stream of records on a Kafka topic. I have another set of unique IDs. I need to, for each record in the stream, check if the stream's ID is present in the set of unique IDs I have. Basically, this should serve as a filter for my Kafka Streams app. i.e., only to write records of Kafka topic that match the set of Unique IDs I have to another topic.

Our current application is based on Kafka Streams. I looked at KStreams and KTables. Looks like they're good for enrichments. Now, I don't need any enrichments to the data. As for using state stores, I'm not sure how good they are as a scalable solution.

I would like to do something like this:

```
kStream.filter((k, v) -> {
    valueToCheckInKTable = v.get(FIELD_NAME);
    if (kTable.containsKey(valueToCheckInKTable)) return record
    else ignore 
});
```

The lookup data can be pretty huge. Can someone suggest the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the reference IDs into a table via `builder.table("id-topic")` with the ID as primary key (note that the value must be non-null -- otherwise it would be interpreted as a delete -- if there is no actual value, just put any non-null dummy value of each record when you write the IDs into the `id-topic`). To load the full table on startup, you might want to provide a custom timestamp extractor that always returns `0` via `Consumed` parameter on the `table()` operator (record are processed in timestamp order and returning `0` ensure that the record from the `id-topic` are processed first to load the table).

To do the filtering you do a stream-table join:

```java
KStream stream = builder.stream(...);
// the key in the stream must be ID, if this is not the case, you can use `selectKey()` to set a new ke

KStream filteredStream = stream.join(table,...);
```

As you don't want to do any enrichment, the provided `Joiner` function can just return the left stream side value unmodified (and can ignored the right hand side table value).

Comment: Thanks Matthias! Isn't there another way without re-keying the KStream? Can we do a join on values? As in my visualization above, the `valueToCheckInKTable` is the value that needs to be found in the KTable key or value. 

Also, we would need to do an inner join on the `KStream` and `GlobalKTable`, right? Because, I need to write records from `KStream` only if that record matches the lookup KTable key. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If the reference data is small, you could use a `globalKTable()` instead of a regular `KTable` -- because the `GlobalKTable` is replicated it supports a non-key join and thus you can avoid rekeying the `KStream`. For the table (global or regular) the lookup can only be done into the table key. (And yes, you want to do an inner join to mimic the filter.)

Comment: Thanks Matthias! :)